Google Cloud Platform VM disk snapshots are not working, all different sizes
I am having problems creating snapshots of my production VM, every snapshot is a wildly different size.
My disk has around 50gb of data but the snapshots I've made today have been 163mb, 229mb, 1.07gb and 60mb.
Is there a bug in snapshots as of May 2024?
The server is currently in use, but surely the whole point of snapshots is that I can grab a copy of the VM for backup purposes.
Thanks

Sharing this documentation that explains incremental snapshot, based from Snapshot Deletion.

Compute Engine uses incremental snapshots so that each snapshot contains only the data that has changed since the previous snapshot. For unchanged data, snapshots reference the data in previous snapshots. Storage costs for Persistent Disk and Hyperdisk snapshots charge only for the total size of the snapshot.

Here is another link that shows how incremental standard snapshots work.

Snapshots are incremental, so you can create regular snapshots on a Persistent Disk or Hyperdisk faster and at a lower cost compared to regularly creating a full image of the disk.

More information is shown from the links shared, if by chance this information did not match your concern and might be a possible issue, you can follow the information that I shared below.
Upon checking the Google Status link there are no ongoing bug regarding your snapshot concern, you can also explore this by clicking on the View History Then search for compute engine or snapshot service to check the history of bug which upon checking there are no current bug or issue that is created with your concern.
If you think that this is an issue, you may visit this link to check how Google handles this kind of issue. As per documentation

Sometimes one of our staff will ask for clarification or followup. After we're able to replicate the issue, we'll tell you that it's been forwarded to the appropriate team.

To create an issue regarding this concern here are the steps from this link

Thanks - I will try building a new VM from the latest scheduled snapshot and see how my database is looking
